# Inserir Imagem em uma tabela ja criada

Tags: php, imagem, tabela-html, relacionamento

Tenho duas tabelas - `alunos(id, nome, email...)` e `fotos(id, imagem, id_aluno)`. Preciso acrescentar uma imagem a cada aluno já criado.

Tive ideia de fazer um `select` que apareca todos os alunos e então, selecionando, acrescentar a imagem um a um.
Gostaria que me ajudassem a adicionar a foto usando chave estrangeira.

PS: Sou novo em php, mas já fiz um método pra adicionar as fotos, quero saber agora como adicionar relacionando a foto ao aluno que aparece no select.

Desde já agradeço.

```
//<?php


$conn = @mysql_connect("localhost", "......", ".......") or die ("Problemas na conexão.");
$db = @mysql_select_db("bancoTeste", $conn) or die ("Problemas na conexão");

    ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);


if($_POST['cadastrar']){

    // Recupera os dados dos campos
    $foto = $_FILES["foto"];



        // Verifica se o arquivo é uma imagem
        if(!preg_match("/^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/", $foto["type"])){
           $error[1] = "Isso não é uma imagem.";
        } 

        // Se não houver nenhum erro
        if (count($error) == 0) {

            // Pega extensão da imagem
            preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $foto["name"], $ext);

            // Gera um nome único para a imagem
            $nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];

            // Caminho de onde ficará a imagem
            $caminho_imagem = "fotosMex/" . $nome_imagem;

            // Faz o upload da imagem para seu respectivo caminho
            move_uploaded_file($foto["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem);



            // Insere os dados no banco
            $inserir = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM alunos");
            $inserir = mysql_insert_id();

            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fotosTeste VALUES('', '".$nome_imagem."', '".$inserir."')");



            // Se os dados forem inseridos com sucesso
            if ($sql){
                echo "Você foi cadastrado com sucesso.";
            }else{

                echo "nao enviada";
            }
        }

        // Se houver mensagens de erro, exibe-as
        if (count($error) != 0) {
            foreach ($error as $erro) {
                echo $erro . "<br />";
            }
        }

}

?>

//<!--<!DOCTYPE html>
// <html lang="pt-br">
 //<head>
// <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 /  <title>Cadastro</title>
 /</head>
 /<body>



 //<h1>Cadastro de Usuário</h1>
 //<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" //enctype="multipart/form-data" name="cadastro" >

 //<label>Selecione um aluno</label>

 //<select name="alunos">

 //<option>Alunos</option>

 //<?php 
 //$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alunos");

 //while ($aluno = mysql_fetch_object($sql,MSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>

            <option value="<?php $aluno['id'] ?>"

            <?php if ($aluno['id'] == $_POST['alunos']) { 
                echo "selected";
            }  ?>>

            <?php echo $aluno['pess_nome'];  ?>


            </option>
 //<?php } ?>

  //</select>


            <input type="file" name="foto"/>
            <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar"/><br/>



 </form>
 </body>
 </html> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Faz um loop (select na tabela alunos) dentro deste loop cria o INSERT INTO fotos (id, imagem, id_aluno) VALUES (id, imagem, id_aluno)

Ai no SELECT para ver as fotos você pode dar um INNER JOIN em fotos ON (fotos.id_aluno = alunos.id)

Comment: ola rafael, voce poderia me mostrar na sintaxe do PHP, se não for muito incomodo. Não é comodismo, é porque ja estou quebrando a cabeça a um tempo e minha ultima opção foi perguntar a alguem.

Answer (score 0):

"quero saber agora como adicionar relacionando a foto ao aluno que aparece no select"
Estou entendendo que a sua dúvida é especificamente como passar o id do aluno para a página php.

Quando criar o seu select use o Id de cada aluno no atributo valor.

```
<select id="alunos">
  <option value="1">Aluno-1</option>
  <option value="2">Aluno-2</option>
  <option value="3">Aluno-3</option>
  <option value="4">Aluno-4</option>
</select>
```

Quando vc apertar o botao para gravar as alterações use o seguinte javascript para mandar esse id para a sua pagina php. Estou assumindo que vc não vai usar AJAX.

```
//Usando jQuery
<script>
    $(function(){

        $(document).on("click keydown", "#btn_sendFile", function(e){
         e.preventDefault();//Previne o comprtamento send by default
         var alunoID = $("#alunos").val();
         //alert(alunoID);//Para teste
         window.location = "minhaPage.php?alunoIDjS="+alunoID;//alunoIDjS é uma variavel para ser usada na proxima pagina, minhaPage.php
      }); //End of $(document).on("change", ...    
    });//End of $(function(){
</script>
```

Na sua página php use:

```
<?php

$alunoId = $_POST["alunoIDjS"]; //Vai recuperar o valor do alunoID

//O seu código para recuperar a foto

//Use $alunoId no seu sql....

?>
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, minha pagina ja contem todo o codigo.

Comment: alem disso, como faço na hora do insert?

Comment: Veja essa parte do seu código: "// Insere os dados no banco". Vc não prcisa fazer um select para recuperar o id do aluno pois esse valor está sendo passado pela varíavel `$alunoId`. Deve ficar assim: `$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fotosTeste VALUES('', '".$nome_imagem."', '".$alunoId."')");`

Comment: Logo abaixo de `// Recupera os dados dos campos` vc vai inserir `$alunoId = $_POST["alunoIDjS"];` e continua com o seu código.

Comment: vc só vai mudar o seu javascrip na sua página onde tem o HTML. Usa o javascript que te enviei. Não esqueça de fazer o link com o jquery. Use o seguinte endereço CDN` <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`